# Why isn't my adminhtml "new" action page not showing in Magento?

Tags: magento

For this in the admin panel `/brands/adminhtml_brand/new/` for my custom module, I am supposed to be seeing a page when I want to add a new entry to the database. I am [following this tutorial](http://codemagento.com/2011/02/grids-and-forms-in-the-admin-panel/). And my `layout.xml` is setup correctly.

[image: magento cannot edit]

**BrandController.php**

```
class Desbest_Brands_Adminhtml_BrandController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
    public function editAction()
        {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', null);
            $model = Mage::getModel('brands/example');
            if ($id) {
                $model->load((int) $id);
                if ($model->getId()) {
                    $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
                    if ($data) {
                        $model->setData($data)->setId($id);
                    }
                } else {
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('brands')->__('Example does not exist'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                }
            }
            Mage::register('example_data', $model);

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
            $this->renderLayout();
      }
 }
```

**Edit.php**

```
<?php 
class Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Example_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'brands';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_example';
        $this->_mode = 'edit';

        $this->_addButton('save_and_continue', array(
                  'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
                  'onclick' => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
                  'class' => 'save',
        ), -100);
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('brands')->__('Save Example'));

        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function toggleEditor() {
                if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('form_content') == null) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'edit_form');
                } else {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'edit_form');
                }
            }

            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
            }
        ";
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if (Mage::registry('example_data') && Mage::registry('example_data')->getId())
        {
            return Mage::helper('brands')->__('Edit Example "%s"', $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('example_data')->getName()));
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('brands')->__('New Example');
        }
    }

}
```

**Grid.php**

```
<?php
class Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Example_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('example_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('desc');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('brands/example')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('brands')->__('ID'),
            'align'     =>'right',
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('attributelabelid', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('brands')->__('Name'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('brands')->__('Description'),
            'align'     =>'left',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the URL you're attempting to access, your controller action should be `newAction()`, not `editAction()`, unless you already have newAction() forwarding to edit as in the tutorial.

The tutorial you linked to included a forward from the newAction to the editAction, using this:

```
public function newAction()
{
    $this->_forward('edit');
}
```

So, either make sure that you're using that forward, or access the controller at `/brands/adminhtml_brand/edit/` instead, and if you do this, be sure to update your layout handle to target the edit route.

Some things to do to troubleshoot:

- First off, post all the relevant code to the SO question - including layout xml updates
- Always include full class names or file paths of all magento classes / files.  Because it doesn't seem like you've done something obviously wrong, it will probably come down to some trivial thing like a typo or mismatched block type / name - that kind of thing has happened to me many times.
- Disable cache if you haven't already
- Enable block template hints so you know for sure which templates and blocks are being pulled into the page.
- Check exception.log, system.log, and also your PHP error log to see if there's anything in there.

Comment: I changed `public function editAction()` to `public function newAction()` and it didn't do anything. `layout.xml` is here. https://gist.github.com/c12cea66b6c6e3b1c43a

Comment: @sparcksoft is right. If you change it into new action, you have to modified your layout.xml too, change the handle from 'brands_adminhtml_brand_edit' into 'brands_adminhtml_brand_new'

Comment: I changed it to `brands_adminhtml_brand_edit` and I'm getting the same result. How am I supposed to give you the full class names? I have given you all the necessary classes (I would think), in my question. Do you mean what's inside the Block folder?

Comment: Sorry the controller is the only one that you didn't post the full class name for. Many times I've had a typo in a class name or te wrong path, that kin of thing. And yes, layout handle needs to change as ivantedja said.

Comment: Oh and also check system.log and exception.log, see if maybe there's an error being thrown about a missing block.

Comment: Updated my answer with these suggestions for completeness.

Comment: Again as @sparcksoft said, if you're using editAction, there should be newAction that contains forward to editAction. Hi sparcksoft how about updating your answer to make it clear, what shoud be done when using editAction (forward) or newAction (change handle name in layout)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I managed to fix one unrelated error (due to a spelling mistake in the tutorial). The class name for BrandController.php is called `Desbest_Brands_Adminhtml_BrandController` which is specified by `adminhtml/default/default/Desbest_Brands/layout.xml`

Comment: Not really. The `brands/adminhtml_brand/new` webpage in the admin panel is still coming up blank.

Comment: What is `exception ''Invalid block type: Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Example_Edit'` supposed to mean, if Edit.php has a real class called `Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Example_Edit` ?

Comment: Post your config.xml - let's see if your <blocks> node is setup right.

Comment: The config.xml is referencing adminlayout.xml but you said you named the file layout.xml. That would be a problem. Also please update the question with corrected information (new action vs edit action) and include all code snippets within the question itself. Each time u include a code snippet include the path to the file as the first line of the snippet. This is gonna come down to a minor discrepancy somewhere so having all the I's dotted and t's crossed is important.

Comment: One thing I'll do quickly if I'm suspecting that an XML file somewhere that I'm expecting to be loaded isn't actually being loaded is to break the XML file, refresh, an make sure that an error is thrown. Otherwise either the XML file path has a mismatch or caching could be an. Issue. (written from iPhone)

Comment: I like the idea of breaking the XML file, that's what I always do to check if my layout is loaded or not.

Comment: There are **2 different** layout XML files. The config.xml is for the frontend which is irrelevant as I got that to work, and the adminlayout.xml is for the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having an issue with ACL (magento security).

See [here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication) for more details.

Comment: There are no `<acl></acl>` tags in my config.xml